# What's the simplest way to assign list members to different variables?

Tags: python

The only way i could do this was:

```
var1 = list[0]
var2 = list[1]
var3 = list[2]
var4 = list[3]
...
```

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = l
```

This assumes `l` is exactly 4 elements long. Most of the time, you want that, but if you don't,

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = l[:4]
```

will ignore extra elements.

Comment: What if one of the variables is also a list supposed to get 4 members of the other list? Can the list and the other variables be assigned in the same statement?

Comment: In Python 3, `thing1, thing2, *four_things = l[:6]`. There's no good way to specify that `four_things` should have exactly 4 things and error if it doesn't, though. If you're on Python 2, `thing1, thing2 = l[:2]; four_things = l[2:6]`.

Comment: The asterisk in `*four_things` is necessary in this case? If so, why?

Comment: Without the asterisk, `thing1, thing2, four_things = l[:6]` would attempt to unpack `l[:6]` as a sequence of three elements (maybe it is one!) and assign the elements to `thing1`, `thing2`, and `four_things`. The `*` denotes extended sequence unpacking. You could write `thing1, *four_things, thing2 = l[:6]` to assign the first and last items of `l[:6]` to `thing1` and `thing2` and put the rest in `four_things`.

Comment: Wait, isn't `*four_things` a tuple?

Comment: [Surprisingly, no.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#specification) It was decided that the ease of further editing a list beat consistency with function `*args`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var1, var2, var3, var4 = alist
```

The number of names should be as many as the length of list, or there will be an error. If you have no need to have all the variables, you can use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use sequence unpacking on a slice of the list:

```
var1, var2, var3 = lst[:3]
```

If you want to unpack the *whole* list, you don't need to slice it:

```
var1, var2, var3 = lst
```

The last snippet will fail if `lst` doesn't have exactly three elements.